# Elastic Search Auto completion return only the first match prefix in completion suggest field input

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I tried to use the completion suggester feature of elastic but when i fill the suggest input field with words with the same prefix it return only one of them.

for example a sample of my document suggest field

"msSuggest": {
   "input": [
          "Hair",
          "Hair loss treatment",
          "الشعر",
          "علاج تساقط الشعر"]
}

when i write **h** >>>>>>result if Hair **only**
when i write **hair l** >>>>>>>result is Hair loss treatment

so not both returned when i input **h**

**The suggest query (Nest)**

```
var response = await _elasticSearchClient.SearchAsync<OffersModel>(s => s
                 .Index<OffersModel>()
                 .Index(new[] { indexName })
                 .Source(x => x.Includes(g => g.Fields(f => f.HgroupsAR, f => f.HgroupsEN, f => f.Suggest)))
                 //.Query(q => q.QueryString(qq => qq.Query("suggest:*horm*")))
                 .Suggest(su => su                    
                 .Completion("hgs", cs => cs
                     .Field(f => f.msSuggest)
                     .Prefix(query)
                     .SkipDuplicates()
                 )
```

Comment: Please show your suggest query as well.

Comment: i had edited the question and added the suggestion query @Val